# find trigram using NLTK

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, n-gram

I am not very familiar with [NLTk](http://nltk.org/) and python, and I have to do the following tasks in a program:

1. **Tokenize** and lowercase the input *text1*
2. **Tokenize** the input *text2*
3. Find all **trigrams** in the input *text1*

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Without showing your own efforts "can anyone help" sounds rather like "can anyone do this for me". The answer is probably no.

Comment: It also sounds suspiciously like homework...

Answer (score 0):

Are `text1` and `text2` part of the nltk examples? Then take a look at them and you'll discover that tokenizing is not as much work as you may think :-)

For lowercasing, look at any introductory python tutorial. For trigrams, look in the nltk book.

Answer (score 0):

In case you do not want to use nltk ngrams:

```
    """import nltk
    from nltk import word_tokenize

    text1 = "I really like python"
    text2 = " Python is a snake"
    token=nltk.word_tokenize(text1)
    token=nltk.word_tokenize(text2)
    low_text1=nltk.word_tokenize(text1.lower())
    N = 3
    grams = [low_text1[i:i+N] for i in xrange(len(low_text1)-N+1)]"""
```

Answer (score -1):

in case if you don't have an example for that
about to find all trigram you should first tokenize it

```
>>> import nltk
>>> from nltk import word_tokenize
>>> from nltk.util import ngrams
>>> text1 = "Hi How are you? i am fine and you"
>>> token=nltk.word_tokenize(text1)    #tokenize your text 
>>> tttt=nltk.word_tokenize(text.lower())  #tokenize your text and make it lowercase in onestep
>>> tttt
['hi', 'how', 'are', 'you', '?', 'i', 'am', 'fine', 'and', 'you']

>>> trigrams=ngrams(token,3)          # find all the trigram in text1
>>> trigrams
[('Hi', 'How', 'are'), ('How', 'are', 'you'), ('are', 'you', '?'), ('you', '?', 'i'), ('?', 'i', 'am'), ('i', 'am', 'fine'), ('am', 'fine', 'and'), ('fine', 'and', 'you')]
```

about make your text2 you need just to apply the tokenize step